# Draw type stuck on wireframe and no model when rendered

Tags: 3d-view, wireframe

My draw type is not on wireframe but all I see is this:

[image]

What can I do to fix this?

Version 2.49b

edit: Link as requested

https://www.mediafire.com/?u93956gqgss45pk

Comment: Why are you using Blender 2.4x?

Comment: Version we use at my college

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to talk to your professor about upgrading to 2.5x or learning that version in your spare time. 2.4x is now obsolete for the most part. The modeling tools are old, the interface is extremely cumbersome and there is _no_ new content (tutorials, updates etc) being made for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very hard to understand how your models managed to end up like this but the reason they appear like that and don't render is because they have no faces. Blender *won't* render lone edges or vertices. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *Edit* mode and select `4` vertices on any of the objects and press <kbd>F</kbd> to create a face.

I would recommend recreating the scene instead of trying to fill in the missing faces.